# Pandas: append column values as new rows

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
   200003  200003.1
0     123       456
```

I want to transform it like this:

```
       200003
    0     123
    1     456
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

**Edit:**
`df.stack()` returns

```
0  200003      123
   200003.1    456
dtype: int64
```

My goal is to use `df.to_dict('records')` to be able to transform the df into a format suitable for machine learning like this `[{'200003': '123'}, {'200003': '456'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`DataFrame.stack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

Answer to your edit:

```
stacked = df.stack()
stacked.index = [df.columns[0]] * stacked.shape[0]
```

and then:

```
out = [ {j[0]:j[1]} for j in list(zip(stacked.index, stacked.values)) ]
```

gives you the list of dicts you are looking for.

Comment: It looks like this will add a new level '200003.1' to the index 0, which is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What do you mean? show output. Do you mean that the column name is not what you want it to be?

Comment: df.stack() returns 
    0  200003      123
        200003.1    456
I need both the 123 and 456 values to be assigned to the column 200003. I am trying to use df.to_dict() to be able to create an array like `[{'200003': '123'}, {'200003': '456'}]`. The way the df is transformed using df.stack() prevents me from doing this.

Comment: Edited the answer to get the list of dicts you asked for

Comment: Thanks. Minor comment is it should be `{j[0]: j[1]}`. Now what if I had many columns like 200003,200003,200001? This code should be scalable to be able to support that scenario.

Comment: You're perfectly right about the `:`. Your question pretains to the special case you mentioned. For general, I think it's better to put in new question with an reproducible example.